# Kafka addtional partition key or partitoner without key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I`m new in Kafka and have some problems.
 I know that we can implenent Partitioner class with own partion logic which return specific partiton depending on message key. Also we can set log compaction policy under which only the latest version of messages with same key are stored. 
But I need to have different keys for message for this actions. For example, we have entity with id and address(city_id). I want to choose partition depending on city_id and store only latest info about people with same id. Is there any way to solve this problem? 
Sorry for my bad English, I really want to learn Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

Is it absolutely necessary that all messages with the same city go to the same partition? If yes, why? Can you present your use case that requires that?

If not, you could just include both `city_id` and `person_id` in hash calculation. That way compaction should remove all but the latest person message (provided that you have 1 to 1 mapping from person to city, which is usually true in schemas)?

Comment: I need post messages in different partiton by city_id because I want use consumers which will consume only specific partition